# Why is ammonia less acidic than terminal alkynes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, water

Here's a picture from Organic Chemistry by Solomons, Fryhle & Snyder :

[image]
Why is it that ammonia is less acidic than terminal alkynes even though water, and even alcohols, are more acidic than them?

Water and ammonia seem to be very similar to me:

- Electronegativity difference of oxygen and nitrogen is only 0.4 (Pauling scale)
- Both are very similar and differ by only number of hydrogen atoms.
- Both are $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridized
- Oxygen and nitrogen atoms have similar size

However, the difference in acidic strength is **huge**. If my understanding of $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values is correct, water is nearly $10^{10}$ times **more** acidic than terminal alkynes, whereas ammonia is **less** acidic than terminal alkynes by a factor of $10^{13}$!

Shouldn't the list be like: water > alcohols > ammonia > terminal alkynes > terminal alkenes > alkanes **or** water > ammonia > alcohols > amines > terminal alkynes > terminal alkenes > alkanes ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is the alkyne that is not in line. 
In the alkynes, the carbon is *sp* hybridized and this gives it much more *s* character. 
Because of this, the electrons are closer to the carbon nucleus and the $\ce{C-H}$ bond is slightly polarized. 
The carbon has some δ - and the hydrogen δ +.

Therefore the terminal alkynes are more acidic and have a lower $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ than ammonia.

Comment: Ok ... so, I googled the $pK_a$ of HF and it's $3.17$. Seems like a change of around $10$ $pK_a$ is normal when moving in the second period. So, my next question would be — how can we, theoretically, assign acidity order for terminal alkenes and alkynes? Is there any data on the electronegativity (if that's the right term) of carbon in $sp^2$ and $sp$ hybridisation? I read a [question](https://www.quora.com/Is-sp2-carbon-more-electronegative-than-nitrogen) related to this on Quora which uses %s character to find the E.N. of $sp$ carbon, but the reasoning is not very convincing.

Comment: Please ask this as a new question, explaining that it follows up from this one.

Comment: Just a reminder: Atoms are not hybridised, only orbitals are. Therefore: Carbon utilises sp hybrid orbitals for the C-H bond.